# Translation string extraction

Tags: javascript, regex, string, typescript, extract

We have a translation extraction tool that we've written, that extracts strings that we've marked for translation in TypeScript. The JavaScript tool reads our Typescript files and has a regex like:

```
fileContent.match(/this.\translate\((.*?));/);
```

(simplified for readability, this works fine)

The translation method takes 3 parameters: 1. The string to be translated, 2. any variables that might be interpolated, 3. description. The last 2 are optional. 
Examples of the implementation:

```
this.translate('text to translate');
this.translate('long text' + 
               'over multiple lines');
this.translate(`text to translate with backticks for interpolation`);
this.translate(`some test with a ${variable}`, [variable]);
this.translate(`some test with a ${variable}`, [variable], 'Description');
```

We need to extract these 3 parameters from text in JavaScript and have issues parsing it. We are currently using a regex to check the first opening string character (`'` or "`") and trying to match a closing character, but that is hard to do.

I'm currently trying to use `eval` (the script doesn't run in the browser, but CLI), like this:

```
function getParameters(text, variables, description){ 
    return {text: text, variables: variables, description: description}
}
toEval = string.replace('this.translate', 'getParameters');
eval(toEval);
```

Which works perfect if there are no variables, but complains that `"variables" not defined`, when we pass in variables.

Can anyone suggest a good/better way to deal with this text extraction?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of regex, you can use either babel or webpack to properly parse Javascript (or typescript) and extract all the information.

I have a webpack plugin that works on static strings only, but it should give a good starting point:
https://github.com/grassator/webpack-extract-translation-keys

Comment: Thanks, how would that work with the example strings that I've provided?